# How to stop additional dropdown menu items from disappearing when submenu is open?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, dropdown

Terribly worded question, but let me elaborate:

I am building a dropdown menu for mobile/tablet screens and within the main menu I have a submenu for one of the items. The menu should read as below with Services opening a submenu within the element.

- Home
- Services

  - Painting
  - Interior
  - Exterior
  - Additional Services
- Testimonials
- Contact

So far, aesthetically, the menu opens beautifully, however, when I hover beyond the last submenu item (Additional Services) to go to Testimonials or Contact, the entire main-dropdown closes. I'm no expert at CSS/HTML but am comfortable enough with them to figure most things out, if not on my own then with the help of you fine folk on here.

If anyone could help me identify what I'm missing in my coding to keep the main dropdown open once I go beyond the bounds of the main dropdown menu. Apologies for any redundancies in the coding, I'm working on cleaning it up.

[image]

```css
/*Dropdown Properties*/

.tablet-dropdown {
  float: right;
}

.tablet-dropbtn {
  padding-top: 34px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tablet-dropdown .tablet-dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  background-color: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  width: 375px;
  margin-left: -221px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tablet-dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  transform: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.tablet-dropdown:hover .tablet-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  border-top: 10px #0d2d06 solid;
}

.tablet-dropbtn:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/*2nd Dropdown for Services*/

.tablet-dropdown2 {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  background-color: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
}

.tablet-dropbtn2 {
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  background-color: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  z-index: 2;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: #0d2d06 solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tablet-dropdown-content2 a {
  color: #0d2d06;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content2 a:hover {
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  transform: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.tablet-dropdown2:hover .tablet-dropdown-content2 {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px #0d2d06 solid;
}

.tablet-dropbtn2:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/*Dropdown Properties*/

.tablet-dropdown {
  float: right;
}

.tablet-dropbtn {
  padding-top: 34px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tablet-dropdown .tablet-dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  background-color: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  width: 375px;
  margin-left: -221px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tablet-dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  transform: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.tablet-dropdown:hover .tablet-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  border-top: 10px #0d2d06 solid;
}

.tablet-dropbtn:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/*2nd Dropdown for Services*/

.tablet-dropdown2 {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  background-color: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
}

.tablet-dropbtn2 {
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d2d06;
  background-color: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  z-index: 2;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: #0d2d06 solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tablet-dropdown-content2 a {
  color: #0d2d06;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.tablet-dropdown-content2 a:hover {
  background-color: #e0dbd5;
  color: #0d2d06;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  transform: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.tablet-dropdown2:hover .tablet-dropdown-content2 {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px #0d2d06 solid;
}

.tablet-dropbtn2:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="tablet-dropdown">
  <button class="tablet-dropbtn">Menu
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="tablet-dropdown-content">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <div class="tablet-dropdown2">
      <button class="tablet-dropbtn2">Services
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </button>
      <div class="tablet-dropdown-content2">
        <a href="painting.html">Painting</a>
        <a href="interior.html">Interior Remodel</a>
        <a href="exterior.html">Exterior Remodel</a>
        <a href="additional.html">Additional Services</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that the main-dropdown is only shown when you hover over the tablet-dropdown-content.

The tablet-dropdown-content expands when you're hovering over your submenu.

Once you're leaving the space of your submenu, the submenu is collapsed and your tablet-dropdown-content gets smaller as well leaving you with a situation where you are no longer hovering over the "main" dropdown.

I can't really think of a way to address this problem with just CSS.

Suggestions on what to do instead:

1. Apply a fixed-height to the dropdown no matter which sub-menu you're showing
2. Use javascript.